# Ensuring failure atomicity in tree-like structures

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

#### The situation

I've got to handle rather large (>10000 entries) tree structures. Not binary trees but data with a natural hierarchy (for example the children of the root are continents, the children of continents are countries and the children of countries are cities).

Merging is done by recursively pairing up entries with the same name and calculate the union of their children.

```
Europe
  Germany
     Düsseldorf
     Hamburg
(merged with)
Europe
  Belgium
     Mechelen
  Germany
     Stuttgart
(should give)
Europe
  Belgium
     Mechelen
  Germany
     Düsseldorf
     Hamburg
     Stuttgart
```

Entries are always sorted, so you'll never have a case where the same entries appear in different order in different trees.

#### The problem

What's a good way to ensure failure atomicity when merging two such trees? Specifically, the whole merge operation should fail if the trees contain the same leaf entry on the same level.

```
Europe
  Belgium
     Gent
     Mechelen
(merged with)
Europe
  Belgium
     Mechelen
(should fail, because Mechelen appears in both trees under Europe/Belgium)
```

#### What do I mean by "good"?

1. Running time isn't critical, code complexity and memory are the main constraints.
2. Specifically, I want to avoid as much copy-on-write as possible due to the size of the structures.
3. The solution doesn't have to be thread-safe, external synchronization ensures that neither of the trees are accessed while a merge is running.
4. I happen to be using Java but any imperative pseudo-code will do.

Comment: What does "merge" mean here?

Comment: From your description, isn't it enough to just firstly check if there is a conflicting entry on any level?

Comment: Good question, updated my answer to make the problem clearer.

Comment: Hmm, I can possibly make two passes, yes.

Comment: You probably wouldn't have to duplicate very much code given a flag `boolean doMerge` that enables/disables the destructive operations.

Comment: 10k qualifies as *large*? My first guess for checking for duplicate nodes per level would be to build a Map<Node, Integer> (integer representing the level) and if put(Node, Level) returned non null you have a conflict. For 10-100k entries the Map will need a few MB tops.

Comment: @Durandal Not large, let's say large-ish. It's large enough that blindly copying the entire structure before every operation becomes a nuisance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think David Eisenstat already gives a feasible option.

As Durandal mentions, you could check for duplicate nodes before starting the merge operation.

Another possible way which is easy if you already have a way to calculate the **intersection** of the two trees, is to calculate this and proceed with the merge if it is empty and throw an exception otherwise. It seems that you expect the intersection to be either empty or very small, so this shouldn't take much space. You could also adjust the code to immediately stop when an intersecting element is found.

(The most natural alternative which I think you have ruled out because of space requirements: create a new tree that is a copy of your original tree. Do the merge operation on the new tree and on success continue working with the new tree. This approach is similar to how immutable objects like Java's String do their operations.)